# thymeleaf generate REST url with dynamic parameters/elements

Tags: spring, rest, url, thymeleaf

I would like to create REST url with thymeleaf. I've something like this:

```
<a th:href="@{customer/(${c.id})/edit}">Edit</a>
```

The output is:
`http://localhost:8080/app/customer/($%7Bs.id%7D)/edit`

But I would like to get: `http://localhost:8080/app/customer/4/edit`

How can I achive this? please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you need called [Preprocessing](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/usingthymeleaf.html#preprocessing), just follow the link!

In your case, you should do it like this:

```
<a th:href="@{customer/__${c.id}__/edit}">Edit</a>
```